# Selecting first cell with numeric data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to find a way to select the first numeric value in column A, and then delete all data from that entire row and all rows below it - anyone have any code that can help?

Comment: show your "battle" code and state its actual issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim x
x = [MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A1:A1000),0),0)]
If Not IsNumeric(x) Then Exit Sub
Rows(x & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
End Sub
```